# PfSense 2.3.2-RELEASE1 Port Forward not Working

Tags: nat, port, pfsense

I'm trying to forward port 43594 to my local ip 192.168.0.49. I've added a NAT and rule for the port but I'm still not able to recieve connections. I've restarted my PfSense box and my own computer and still no luck.

Here is the NAT rule:
[image]

Here is the firewall rule
[image]

And here is what Diagnostics->States show for port 43594
[image]

And here is a packet capture on my internal interface filtering port 43593:
[image]

Any idea why traffic is being blocked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the NAT rules you set destination address as WAN address instead of LAN (192.168.0.49 that you pointing to is obviously LAN)